# Controlled folder access blocked imager but no notifications from Windows defender in notification bar

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender

I was attempting to use the Raspberry Pi imager - and it kept failing, it is a 32GB drive so I had to use the erase first or manually format as FAT32 -
I found I could format the drive using the Storage manager , or on oher machines but then the attempt by the Raspberry Pi imager  to erase or put an image on would overwrite the partition information , indicated by loss of all data on the disk , but then would fail soon after .

After a few attempts the Imager said it appears SecureFolderAccess is enabled .... (I dont know why it didnt always tell me ) so I ran the command

```
Set-MpPreference -EnableControlledFolderAccess Disabled
```

and it now works

The feature seems like a good idea and I'm sure I'll work out how to add the imager to the list of allowed application

However what I would like is for Windows Defender Notifications of this failure to be appear. Is this possible?

This is my current setting - theres a lot and a few are just numbers so I'm not sure what to change

> AllowNetworkProtectionOnWinServer             : False AttackSurfaceReductionOnlyExclusions          :
> AttackSurfaceReductionRules_Actions           :
> AttackSurfaceReductionRules_Ids               :
> CheckForSignaturesBeforeRunningScan           : False CloudBlockLevel
> : 0 CloudExtendedTimeout                          : 0 ComputerID
> : 69274C2A-8D4B-4583-AFC5-B652445A8C19
> ControlledFolderAccessAllowedApplications     : {C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Common
> Files\Acronis\TrueImageHome\TrueImageHomeService.exe}
> ControlledFolderAccessProtectedFolders        : DisableArchiveScanning
> : False DisableAutoExclusions                         : False
> DisableBehaviorMonitoring                     : False
> DisableBlockAtFirstSeen                       : False
> DisableCatchupFullScan                        : True
> DisableCatchupQuickScan                       : True
> DisableCpuThrottleOnIdleScans                 :
> DisableDatagramProcessing                     : False
> DisableEmailScanning                          : True
> DisableIntrusionPreventionSystem              : DisableIOAVProtection
> : False DisablePrivacyMode                            : False
> DisableRealtimeMonitoring                     : False
> DisableRemovableDriveScanning                 : True
> DisableRestorePoint                           : True
> DisableScanningMappedNetworkDrivesForFullScan : True
> DisableScanningNetworkFiles                   : False
> DisableScriptScanning                         : False
> EnableControlledFolderAccess                  : 0
> EnableFileHashComputation                     : False
> EnableLowCpuPriority                          : False
> EnableNetworkProtection                       : 0 ExclusionExtension
> : ExclusionIpAddress                            : ExclusionPath
> : ExclusionProcess                              : {C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Common
> Files\Acronis\TrueImageHome\TrueImageHomeService.exe}
> HighThreatDefaultAction                       : 0
> LowThreatDefaultAction                        : 0 MAPSReporting
> : 2 MeteredConnectionUpdates                      : False
> ModerateThreatDefaultAction                   : 0 PUAProtection
> : 0 QuarantinePurgeItemsAfterDelay                : 90
> RandomizeScheduleTaskTimes                    : True
> RealTimeScanDirection                         : 0
> RemediationScheduleDay                        : 0
> RemediationScheduleTime                       : 02:00:00
> ReportingAdditionalActionTimeOut              : 10080
> ReportingCriticalFailureTimeOut               : 10080
> ReportingNonCriticalTimeOut                   : 1440
> ScanAvgCPULoadFactor                          : 50
> ScanOnlyIfIdleEnabled                         : True ScanParameters
> : 1 ScanPurgeItemsAfterDelay                      : 15 ScanScheduleDay
> : 0 ScanScheduleQuickScanTime                     : 00:00:00
> ScanScheduleTime                              : 02:00:00
> SevereThreatDefaultAction                     : 0 SharedSignaturesPath
> : SignatureAuGracePeriod                        : 0
> SignatureBlobFileSharesSources                :
> SignatureBlobUpdateInterval                   : 60
> SignatureDefinitionUpdateFileSharesSources    :
> SignatureDisableUpdateOnStartupWithoutEngine  : False
> SignatureFallbackOrder                        :
> MicrosoftUpdateServer|MMPC SignatureFirstAuGracePeriod
> : 120 SignatureScheduleDay                          : 8
> SignatureScheduleTime                         : 01:45:00
> SignatureUpdateCatchupInterval                : 1
> SignatureUpdateInterval                       : 0 SubmitSamplesConsent
> : 1 ThreatIDDefaultAction_Actions                 :
> ThreatIDDefaultAction_Ids                     : UILockdown
> : False UnknownThreatDefaultAction                    : 0
> PSComputerName                                :

Answer (score 0):

My experience with Controlled Folder Access has been less than stellar; most tragically it's stopped game saves for hours of gameplay. I was constantly whitelisting, and I remember it stopping USOCoreWorker (Windows update exe) from doing its job during updates. I disabled it in favour of enabling other Defender options. Also backups and keep it in the cloud.

As far as I understand, it's intended for business use where you won't be seeing a lot of new apps/random events.

what OS version are you running? I ask as it might have improved since the last feature update.

Comment: It is not answer, please use comments instead